# Showing that this sequence converges weakly to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I was reading on weak convergence in $L^p$ spaces and an examples was provided, namely, $f_n=n^{1/p}g(nx)$ for $g\in L^p(R)$ and $1\leq p<\infty$ which converges weakly to $0$ but to nothing strongly. I know that for weak convergence one most show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{R}f_nh\,d\mu=\int fh\,d\mu,\quad h\in L^{p'}(R)$$
where $p$ and $p'$ are Holder's conjugate, but I can't seem to show this. If 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{R}f_nh\,d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/p}\int_{R}g(nx)h(x)\,dx$$
now for $r>0$, let $g(nx)=g_1+g_2=\chi_{(-r,r)}g(nx)+\left(1-\chi_{(-r,r)}\right)g(nx)$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/p}\int_{R}g(nx)h(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/p}\left(\int_Rg_1h(x)\,dx+\int_Rg_2h(x)
\,dx\right)$$
By Holder Ineq.,
$$\int_R g_1h(x)\,dx=\int_{-r}^rg(nx)h(x)\,dx\leq\|g\|_1\|h\|_\infty$$
and similarly may be done with $g_2$
leading to 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/p}\int_{R}g(nx)h(x)\,dx\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/p}2\|g\|_1\|h\|_\infty$$
which does not go to $0$. I believe my upperbound does not work. Any ideas in proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target function is that $f=0$, we are to show that
\begin{align*}
\left|\int f_{n}(x)h(x)\right|\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
For simplicity, I will slightly modify the notation in the question. I write $f_{n}(x)=n^{1/p}f(nx)$ for $f\in L^{p}$ and show that $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ weakly.

Assume first that $f$ has compact support, say, $\text{supp}(f)\subseteq\{|x|\leq M\}$ for some $M>0$. Note that 
\begin{align*}
&\left|\int f_{n}(x)h(x)dx\right|\\
&=\left|\int n^{1/p}f(nx)h(x)dx\right|\\
&=\left|\int_{|x|\leq M/n}n^{1/p}f(nx)h(x)dx\right|\\
&\leq\left(\int_{|x|\leq M/n}n|f(nx)|^{p}dx\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_{|x|\leq M/n}|h(x)|^{p'}dx\right)^{1/p'}\\
&=\|f\|_{L^{p}}\left(\int_{|x|\leq M/n}|h(x)|^{p'}dx\right)^{1/p'}\\
&\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
since $h\in L^{p'}$.

In general, since continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^{p}$, we can pick a $\varphi$ such that $\|f-\varphi\|_{L^{p}}$ is small.

As before, denote that $\varphi_{n}(x)=n^{1/p}\varphi(nx)$.

As a result,
\begin{align*}
&\left|\int f_{n}(x)h(x)dx\right|\\
&\leq\left|\int(f_{n}(x)-\varphi_{n}(x))h(x)dx\right|+\left|\int\varphi_{n}(x)h(x)dx\right|\\
&\leq\|f_{n}-\varphi_{n}\|_{L^{p}}\|h\|_{L^{p'}}+\left|\int\varphi_{n}(x)h(x)dx\right|.
\end{align*}
We also note that
\begin{align*}
\|f_{n}-\varphi_{n}\|_{L^{p}}&=\left(\int|f_{n}(x)-\varphi_{n}(x)|^{p}dx\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\left(n\int|f(nx)-\varphi(nx)|^{p}dx\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\|f-\varphi\|_{L^{p}},
\end{align*}
which is also small.

Comment: How did you come to know that the integral tends to $0$?

Comment: You meant $\displaystyle\int_{|x|\leq M/n}\cdots\rightarrow 0$? Do you know a fact that, if $k\in L^{1}$, then $\displaystyle\int_{|x|\leq1/n}|k(x)|dx\rightarrow 0$? This can be done by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, or actually Monotone Convergence Theorem will do as well.

Comment: Yes, please state what you mean exactly.

Comment: Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem will do.

Comment: Where did you show the point wise convergence?

Comment: So you are concerning $\chi_{|x|\leq 1/n}|k(x)|$, and $\chi_{|x|\leq 1/n}|k(x)|\rightarrow 0$ except for $x=0$, but this doesn't matter. And we have $\chi_{|x|\leq 1/n}|k(x)|\leq|k(x)|$, so Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem applies.